# How to Create Dataset that Mimics Twoway Tabulate, But Sorted in Special Way

Tags: sorting, stata

Begin with the following toybox data:

```
clear all
set obs 150
set seed 1234
foreach i in 1 2 {
    gen year`i' = round(runiform()*4)
    tostring year`i', replace
    replace year`i' = "AA" if year`i'=="0"
    replace year`i' = "BB" if year`i'=="1"
    replace year`i' = "CC" if year`i'=="2"
    replace year`i' = "DD" if year`i'=="3"
    replace year`i' = "EE" if year`i'=="4"
}
```

My ultimate goal is to create a table in LaTeX that is very similar to what would result from `tab year1 year`:

[image]

except both the rows and columns should be sorted by the results of a oneway tab of year1:

[image]

So it would be something like this:

```
year1   BB   DD   CC   EE   AA
BB      7    7    10   6    9
DD      10   ...
CC
EE
AA
```

The approach I am currently considering is to create a dataset that is in this format, with the first variable containing string values `BB, DD`, etc. Then use `texsave` or something to export the dataset to a tex file.

I am able to get the dataset, but I don't know how to sort it in the way I want:

```
contract year1 year2, f(freq)
reshape wide freq, i(year1) j(year2) string
foreach i in AA BB CC DD EE {
    rename freq`i' `i'
}
```

Result:
[image]

What can I do to now sort it based on the results of the one-way tabulation of `year1`? More precisely, how can I sort `year1` in this way and order the `AA...EE` variables in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a new dataset here. What you want tabulated are just one-to-one mappings of your existing variables, category with highest frequency (of first variable) mapped to lowest values of new variables, and so forth. Hence two new variables will suffice.

```
* simpler code for sandbox 
clear all
set obs 150
set seed 1234
foreach i in 1 2 {
    gen year`i' = word("AA BB CC DD EE", 1 + round(runiform()*4))
}

* main segment 
bysort year1 : gen freq = -_N 
egen YEAR1 = group(freq year1) 
labmask YEAR1, values(year1) 
encode year2, gen(YEAR2) label(YEAR1) 
label var YEAR1 "year1"
label var YEAR2 "year2" 

tab YEAR1 YEAR2 

           |                         year2
     year1 |        BB         DD         CC         EE         AA |     Total
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
        BB |         7          7         10          6          9 |        39 
        DD |        10          9         10          6          2 |        37 
        CC |         6          8          9          4          2 |        29 
        EE |         2          3          9          5          5 |        24 
        AA |         2          6          6          2          5 |        21 
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |        27         33         44         23         23 |       150
```

In more detail: One way to do this is to create new variables for tabulation in which the order is according to the group frequencies of your first variable. Here `egen, group()` is helpful. Twists are

1. You want highest frequency first whereas `egen, group()` would create an integer grouping variable with lowest category first. Hence, sort on the negated frequencies. (Or equivalently, negate the default result of `egen, group()`. That is one more line than the solution above.)
2. It is possible that two or more groups have the same frequency, so we must code generally to break any ties.
3. You want the value labels of this grouping variable to show the original categories. `labmask` (*Stata Journal*) is convenient here: see [this paper for discussion](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0034) and `search labmask, sj` to get a download location.

Once the first variable has value labels, those labels are what is wanted to  `encode` the second variable.

If you still want a new dataset, then

```
contract YEAR?
```

Answer (score 1):

One way -- perhaps not the most elegant, but serviceable -- is to recreate the results of your `tab year1` command using `egen`'s `rowtotal()` function:

```
egen _s = rowtotal(AA BB CC DD EE)
gsort -_s
drop _s
```